# StreamSocket.ConnectAsync throws Exception "HRESULT: 0x8007274C" while using a VPN

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps

the problem: While not using a VPN, the code below works fine. As soon as I connect to my home network via a VPN the, code throws an exception (translated from german):

A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a certain period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007274C).

The target "192.168.180.58" is an another computer within my home network.

Windows Store test code:

```
private async void createConnection(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  HostName target = new HostName("192.168.180.58");
  string port = "8181";
  using (StreamSocket client = new StreamSocket())
  {
    try
    {
      await client.ConnectAsync(target, port);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
      string typeName = ex.GetType().Name;
      string msg = ex.Message;
    }
  }
}
```

I created a Windows Console Program (.NET 4.5.1) that is working in both situations (connected by using vpn and not using a vpn).

Windows Console test code:

```
namespace caPing
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      string target = "192.168.180.58";
      int port = 8181;

      TcpClient client = new TcpClient();
      try
      {
        client.Connect(target, port);
        client.Close();
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        throw;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It looks like that the problem is somehow related to the execution environment for Windows Store Apps (when using a vpn).

What is the problem here and how can I solve it?

Kind regards,

Sörnt

Comment: What is the range of IP addresses in used by the remote network in the VPN? Is it 192.168.*.* ?

Comment: It is 192.168.180.* . 

The IP-Address for my Dev PC is 192.168.180.63 when connected via vpn it is 192.168.180.222.

Comment: Can you try by putting different range of IP addresses on each network? The TCP packets maybe are being forwarded to the remote network.

Comment: Or a different question will be, what happen if you try to connect to  192.168.180.58 from 192.168.180.63 machine?

Comment: The Network settings are fine. I can allways connect with the console application. I can also allways connect by using a telnet client. It is just the Windows App that didn't work while using a VPN.

Comment: Was this ever resolved? I'm having this same problem on the latest Windows 10

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem then i found that

`We can not keep two app running at the same time.`

If Server app is running and then run the client app, the server app will

suspend and the client app will fail with connect.

You can create a server application as a desktop app, so that the client and

server can run at the same time.

From MSDN [Here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/bd3e0c5a-c5f6-49c3-b5b5-e172a813db57/streamsocketconnectasync-error-metro-c).